# Which mode shoud I use for Parity syncing to use trace_ APIs for TXs since current blocks?

Tags: transactions, parity, synchronization

I want to use Parity for fast tracing TXs in blocks which will be synced only after my project start.

So, if I initially run my Parity node with params `—pruning=archive —tracing=on` the synchronization process will be veeeeery long.

May I make an initial sync to current block with `—fast` (`—warp`) param an then restart node in an archive mode with tracing from current time?

Comment: That's, unfortunately, not possible. An archive sync takes around 2 weeks on SSD. If you do not have any SSD yet, you should consider getting one.

Comment: Yes, I've already understood. It was me, who asked you about help with sharing downloaded node. :-)